# Multiline mode in Regex not performing according to documentation

Tags: .net, regex

According to the `.Net Standard`:

> The `RegexOptions.Multiline` option, or the `m` inline option, enables the
> regular expression engine to handle an input string that consists of
> multiple lines. It changes the interpretation of the `^` and `$` language
> elements so that they match the beginning and end of a line, instead
> of the beginning and end of the input string.
>
> By default, `$` matches only the end of the input string. If you specify
> the `RegexOptions.Multiline` option, **it matches either the newline
> character (`\n`) or the end of the input string**.

(emphasis mine)

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options#multiline-mode

This seems to say that `$` matches the newline character.  However this does not seem to be the case.  The code:

```
var m = Regex.Match("123\n456", @"123$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
Console.WriteLine(m.Length);
```

prints `3`, not `4` as would be expected if `$` matched `newline`.

Is this a bug?  A documentation error?

Comment: Looks like a documentation error. `$` is effectively a zero-length assertion that matches the position immediately preceding `\n` (in MultiLine mode) or end of the string

Comment: It is not the first inaccuracy in MSDN, I have already submitted an edit to the .NET API reference docs before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a documentation error as any anchor (`^`, `$`, `\A`, `\Z`, `\z`, `\G`) are zero-width assertions and do not consume any text. Non-consuming patterns only match *positions* inside a string, not the text itself.

If you specify the `RegexOptions.Multiline` option, the `$` anchor matches either the *position immediately before a newline character* (`\n`, line feed (LF) char) or the end of the input string.

Comment: This documentation error also corresponds to an inconsistency with Perl (the inspiration for the .Net Regex language), where $ *does* consume the newline

Comment: @JoelFan If `$` could consume anything in Perl, the result would be a single line [here](https://ideone.com/9FB5KP).